# How to find angle of hough lines detected?

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

[image]

My goal is to detect the fractured bone using open cv. I tried the following code. and got correct canny detection edges.and also found houghlines.But now my job is to detected the fractured spot in the image. Iam not understanding how to proceed further. In some blogs i found the we can determine angle of houghlines to detect that line is not staright. But not knowing how to find angle of houghline in my code. Can someone help?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
img = cv2.imread('bone2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,400,apertureSize =3)
cv2.imshow('canny',edges)
kernel=np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
boneEdges=cv2.morphologyEx(edges,cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT,kernel)
minLineLength =1000
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(boneEdges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)

for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
 cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
 slope=(y2-y1),(x2-x1)
 # print('slope',arctan(slope))
cv2.imwrite('houghlines5.jpg',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031701/how-can-i-determine-the-angle-a-line-found-by-houghlines-function-using-opencv

Answer (score 1):

This function returns a list of rho theta sets where theta is the angle you are looking for. Here are the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlines).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031701/how-can-i-determine-the-angle-a-line-found-by-houghlines-function-using-opencv

Comment: HoughLinesP, which sathwika used in his question, does not return rho and theta, because it returns line segments, not lines.