# How to detect and calculate an angle in image? (spray)

Tags: math, binary, angle

I'm trying write a code to find a nozzle spray angle (image) after binary process. I read something about hough transform to do this but I can't apply correctly. ([Calculating the angle between two lines in an image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357099/calculating-the-angle-between-two-lines-in-an-image-in-python) and [How to find angle of hough lines detected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960007/how-to-find-angle-of-hough-lines-detected))

[image]

For a while I have this:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np  
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_grey = cv2.imread('sprayang.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur (img_grey, (5,5), 0)

th = 0
max_val = 255

    ret, o1 = cv2.threshold(img, th, max_val, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU )
```

And the generated image is that:
[image: Btw I trying to fill this hole too]

Using the angle measurement tool in ImageJ I measured about 90°.

Answer (score 0):

1. **cast 2 horizontal rays (from each direction)**
2. **find first hit with your spray**

   [image: rays]

   let call the 2D points `p0,p1` from left and `p2,p3`
3. **compute angle**

   smaller unsigned angle between 2 vectors in 2D is defined by dot product like this:

   ```
   ang = acos( dot( p1-p0 , p2-p1 ) / (|p1-p0|*|p2-p1|) )

                            (x1-x0)*(x2-x1) + (y1-y0)*(y2-y1)
   ang = acos( ------------------------------------------------------------- )
               sqrt( (x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2 ) * sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )
   ```

Comment: I will try start with this, Spektre. But, sincererly I didn't understand very well. Is this horizontal ray specific? Like, if I change the image, will I change that value too?

Comment: @ViniciusCarreira no you do not need to change image (unless you want to for debug) just select some `y` then `for` loop through `x` from 0 to Width (or vice versa for the opposite direction) , read pixel(x,y) value and if not background stop and remember the last x ... the y values select so that one is near start of the spray cone and one near bottom ... either manualy by mouse or hard-code or from BBOX ...