# Is there a way to find the speed from analog speedometer?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an analog speedometer image, with the needle pointing to the current speed. I am trying to find a way to get the speed that the needle is pointing out to. I tried using [HoughCircles()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html) from OpenCV, but it is throwing an error as the image contains only speedometer and which is a semi-circle. Any resources to help me move forward will be appreciated.

[image: Reference Analog Speedometer]

Comment: Please share some images. An idea would also be to detect needle by color or other methods and calculate angle of needle to get speed.

Comment: Is that an actual photograph? It looks rendered. If it’s rendered, and you don’t have access to the data used to render it, then you can likely assume the thing is always in the same place, all you need to do is detect the needle, which has a unique color, and find its angle.

Comment: Your question is not very well posed. Is the image always centred? Is it always viewed perpendicular or sometimes obliquely? Is the needle always red or sometimes blue? Or green? Is the range on the speedo always 0..140? Is 0 mph always at the same angle? What code have you tried?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes the image is always centered and the needle is red. Everything is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the needle will have a different colour to the rest of the speedometer OR its size is distinctly larger than the rest of the elements on the speedometer (which is often the case), I'll do something like below.

1. Convert the image to grayscale.
2. Apply colour thresholding (or size-based thresholding) to detect the pixel area representing the needle.
3. Use HoughLines() or HoughLinesP() functions in OpenCV to fit a line to the shape you detected in Step 2.
4. Now it's a matter of measuring the angle of the line you generated in Step 3 (example provided here: [How can I determine the angle a line found by HoughLines function using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031701/how-can-i-determine-the-angle-a-line-found-by-houghlines-function-using-opencv))
5. You can then map the angle of the line to the speed through a simple equation (Will need to see an image of the speedometer to generate this).

let me know how it went.

Comment: Thank you for the steps. I was able to get angle of the needle with your reference. But stuck with getting the actual speed after that.

Comment: I would say in counter clockwise direction, taking a horizontal x-axis as zero, roughly -30 degrees would be 140 km/h and 210 degrees would equal to 0 km/h.  You should be able to come up with an equation which ties angle and speed using this information.

Comment: Why would you apply Hough transform to a single shape? You could easily determine the two endpoints of the line, or fit a linear equation through all pixel coordinate. Many options that are much simpler than a Hough transform.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get the current speed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I was suggesting a method along the lines of OP's approach, and went for in-built functions known to OP. I agree there are multiple and simpler implementations.